# mht file : extract to html,js and resources

Tags: browser, html

Is there any tools/ commands to extract a mht file to its component html, js, css and other resource files on Ubuntu 16.04 ? One of my bank'suse this format and though I can open it in chrome was wanted to convert it to html.

Save as saves the html but the styling does not stay.

Comment: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/a/34342881/446106 useful - it recommends a perl script called unmht.  I couldn't find any mhtml files to test, but I was ostensibly able to run `perl unmht -h` on Ubuntu without any dependency problems.

Answer (score 1):

[`unmht`](http://www.volkerschatz.com/unix/uware/unmht.html) didn't work for me (*Can't find Content-Type header - not a MIME HTML file?*)

I just

1. [opened with Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/128801/how-can-i-open-an-mht-file-in-linux-ubuntu#comment1945770_128801)
2. <kbd>Ctrl + u</kbd> and save all the HTML source code manually to an html file.

You can do the same for binary files, saving with the same name as named on the HTML. I know that this is a very shitty way but it was enough/easy/straightforward for me.

Comment: yes back then did not open in ubuntu and the version of chrome that was available then. good they have implemented it now. works on my andrid phone with chrome too, but have to choose Open with (other) every time (on adnroid).